# std::vector of Derived class instances whose Bases contain a (raw) pointer

Tags: c++, stdvector

Say I had the following structure

```
class BaseKernel {
   // .......
}

class DerivedKernel : public BaseKernel {
   // .......
}

class A {
  public:
    A(BaseKernel* kernel) : kernel(kernel) {}
    A(const A& a) : kernel(a.kernel) {}
   ~A() {delete kernel;}

    BaseKernel* kernel;
}

class B : public A {
  public:
    B(BaseKernel* kernel) : A(kernel) {}
    B(const B& b) : A(b) {}
   ~B() = default;
}

class C : public B {
  public:
    C() = default;
    C(BaseKernel* kernel) : B(kernel) {}
    C(const C& c) : B(c) {}
   ~C() = default;
}

class D {
  public:
    D() = default;
    D(std::vector<C> collection) : collection(collection) {}

    std::vector<C> collection;
}

class E {
  public:
    E(std::vector<D> dollection) : dollection(dollection) {} // lmfao, dollection for the lack of a better word
    
    std::vector<D> dollection;
}
```

With the following usage

```
BaseKernel* kernel1 = new DerivedKernel(...);
BaseKernel* kernel2 = new DerivedKernel(...);

C c_obj1(kernel1);
C c_obj2(kernel2);

std::vector<C> collection1(1, c_obj1);
std::vector<C> collection2(1, c_obj2);

std::vector<D> dollections = {collection1, collection2};
// At this point kernel1 and kernel2 are deleted.
E e_obj(dollections) // Useless now
```

As im relatively new to C++ and therefore unfamiliar with smart pointers (i believe the solution is with the latter, however), how would I handle such a case with raw pointers? (Better yet, a solution using the appropriate smart pointer would be great)

The initialization of `c_obj1` and `c_obj2` were fine (`kernel1` and `kernel2` still lives), but specifically for `dollections` I would need to initialize the vector with brackets (as I would have different `collections`)  and after debugging it first goes through the copy constructors then ultimately the destructor `~A()`?

Comment: At first glance this is a problem related to not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Your `A` class is broken when you copy or assign it.

Comment: Hm, having a look through the link you sent, i believe I followed the Rule of 3, however I most likely missed on something a bit more intricate. What do you mean by class `A` being broken?

Comment: For one, you did not implement any assignment operator. Second, your copy constructor does not respect the rule of 3. You are simply copying the pointer, so you can have multiple instances of `A` whose `kernel` member point to the same object. But then each of their destructors always destroys the pointed `kernel`. Once you destroy any `A`, every instance that was copied from it becomes invalidated (there `kernel` now points to a destroyed object). At the very least this will be a problem when you eventually destroy those copies.

Comment: To transfer ownership, you should use move semantics. Objects providing a default constructor taking 0 parameters and move operations can be used as element type of a vector. In your case the simplest way to do this would be to add a default value of `nullptr` to the constructor of `C` and changing `BaseKernel* kernel;` to `std::unique_ptr<BaseKernel> kernel;` and using the default `~A` and adding the necessary defaulted move constructors/assignment operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some problems. I'll see if I can understand your real question. Let's start with this:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(BaseKernel* kernel) : kernel(kernel) {}
    A(const A& a) : kernel(a.kernel) {}
   ~A() {delete kernel;}

    BaseKernel* kernel;
}
```

This is bad. If you use your copy constructor, you'll end up deleting the same data twice. Imagine this:

```
 BaseKernel * k = new BaseKernel();
 A first(k);
 A second(first);
```

This this point, both first.kernel and second.kernel point to k. Now, when they go out of scope, both destructors will attempt to delete their kernel pointer, so k will get deleted twice.

I don't quite understand the question you're asking. However, I discourage the use of raw pointers and encourage smart pointers. `std::unique_ptr` is more efficient, but I tend to always use `std::shared_ptr` as follows:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(std:: shared_ptr <BaseKernel> kernelIn) : kernel(kernelIn) {}
    A(const A& a) : kernel(a.kernel) {}
   ~A() { /* Nothing needed */ }

    std:: shared_ptr <BaseKernel> kernel;
};
```

Then later...

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseKernel> kernel1 = std::make_shared<DerivedKernel>(...);
```

You'll probably need to do a `dynamic_pointer_cast`, though. I usually don't like using the datatype I'm pointing to so would normally not do it here but instead:

```
std::shared_ptr< DerivedKernel> kernel1 = std::make_shared<DerivedKernel>(...);
```

And then dynamic_pointer_cast it as necessary later.

I'm not sure if this gets you further.

Comment: I'd point out that only the first constructor is needed. The copy constructor and the destructor don't serve a purpose anymore, the compiler generated ones are fine. There presence just impedes the compiler, it prevents move semantics.